# How can i get both object length together from chain of object

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Say I create a Object as follows

```
const myObj1 = {
    firstName: "Shaheb",
    lastName: "Ali",
    professions:"Web Developer"
}
```

And create another object with the above object to add as a prototype object

```
const myObj2 = Object.create(myObj1, {
    age:{
      value:33
    },
    edu:{
      value: "MBA"
    }
});
```

now I want to count length of both object together, how can i?

Comment: Neither of your objects has a `.length`. What exactly do you want to count? What is the expected result?

Comment: Objects don't have length really, I presume you want to count the number of keys however in which case you can use `Object.keys(myObj2).length`

Comment: /*When I am trying to get length of object like below its shows 0 for object 2 since it is in prototype chain..*/
/*trying to get length of both object in total*/
  Object.size = function (myObj) { var size = 0, key;
    for(key in myObj){
        if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++
    }
    return size;
  }
      var size = Object.size(myObj1);
      console.log(size); // 3
      var size = Object.size(myObj2);
      console.log(size); // 0

Comment: @shaheb did my suggestion help?

Comment: @shaheb No, it doesn't show 0 because (some of) the keys are on the prototype. It shows 0 because the own keys of `myObj2` are [not enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).

Comment: You are right, is there any way to get them together in a one object?

Comment: @shaheb Don't you want the dynamic prototype inheritance that you used `Object.create` for? Btw, just because your `size` function doesn't count them doesn't mean that you cannot access these properties. `myObj2.lastName` and `myObj2.edu` work just fine.

Comment: @PeterWarrington console.log(Object.keys(myObj2).length) is returning 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to get count of all keys in your object(s). As there is no `length` property available for objects (only for arrays), you should use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), which returns an array with all keys:

```
const myObj1 = {
    firstName: "Shaheb",
    lastName: "Ali",
    professions:"Web Developer"
}
Object.keys(myObj1).length; // would return '3'
```

I believe that instead of `Object.create()`, you actually want to use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which will assign all keys from `myObj1` to `myObj2`:

```js
const myObj1 = {
    firstName: "Shaheb",
    lastName: "Ali",
    professions:"Web Developer"
}

const myObj2 = {
    age:{
      value:33
    },
    edu:{
      value: "MBA"
    }
}

Object.assign(myObj2, myObj1);
document.write(Object.keys(myObj2).length + '<br>'); // return '5'
document.write(Object.keys(myObj1).length); // return '3'
```

Comment: this is works for me to get the let of object, thanks for your help

Comment: @shaheb which comment are you referring to, the one with Object.size function?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the OP goal:

```
const myObj1 = {
    firstName: "Shaheb",
    lastName: "Ali",
    professions:"Web Developer"
}

const myObj2 = {
    age:{
      value:33
    },
    edu:{
      value: "MBA"
    }
};

const result = {...myObj1, ...myObj2};
console.log(result);

const length = Object.keys(result).length;
console.log(length);
```

> { firstName: 'Shaheb',
>   lastName: 'Ali',
>   professions: 'Web Developer',
>   age: { value: 33 },
>   edu: { value: 'MBA' } 
>   }
>
> 5

Answer (score 0):

const obj = Object.create(myObj1, myObj2);
create prototyping object looks like below

> {age: 33, edu: "MBA"}
>         age: 33
>         edu: "MBA"
>         **proto**:
>           firstName: "Shaheb"
>           lastName: "Ali"
>           professions: "Web Developer"
>           **proto**: Object

but assigning a object is like a combining 2object into one. is this not possible to get the length from plan object and prototyping object together?

but your ans was awesome, help me a lot to make it better understand. if it is not possible then i will follow your suggestions.